# regex to replace console code with whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, console-application, vt100

I'm writing some Python tests for a console application that uses [console codes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html), and I'm having some problem gracefully handling the `ESC H` sequence.

I have the `s = r'\x1b[12;5H\nSomething'` input string, I'd like to replace it with     `Something`. I'm trying to use the following regex:

`re.sub(r'\x1b\[([0-9,A-Z]{1,2};([0-9]{1,2})H)', r'\2', s)`

Which of course creates `5Something`.

What I want is something to the effect of

`re.sub(r'\x1b\[([0-9,A-Z]{1,2};([0-9]{1,2})H)', ' '*(int(r'\2')-1), s)`

Which is to create one less than the number of spaces of the second capture group.

I'd also be very happy if there was a way to simply render in a string what I get when I use `print(s)`:

```
    Something
```

I'm using Python 3.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
s = r'\x1b[12;5H\nSomething'
pattern = r'\\x1b\[[0-9A-Z]{1,2};([0-9]{1,2})H\\n'
print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: ' '*(int(x.group(1))-1), s))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##LcuxCsIwFIXhvU9xtySSFFNx0OLg1t3NxiHB0AbaJNymUBGfPVrqdg58f3ylPvhDzm6MAROgLSa4ABK1SNPKqj42yt/CaFPvfEeKqFOy6DeyGtW2e3G6ivvjLXn1qel6t80apfwvQecTRVtOs6H/nsOgR/PUsJyBANnRlSxlh2GOVDImJOMwMZbzFw). See a [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/G1K9jT/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  x1b                      'x1b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9A-Z]{1,2}            any character of: '0' to '9', 'A' to 'Z'
                           (between 1 and 2 times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{1,2}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                             and 2 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  H                        'H'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n                        'n'
```