# Render terminal codes ast text in Python

Tags: python, console-application, paramiko

I'm working with [paramiko-expect](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect) to test some console commands. My problem is that the reply from the application contains a lot of [console codes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html). So far I'm using some regexes to filter out the codes and [render ESC H sequences as spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66216182/6271889). But this has been a hit-and-miss process because it's hard to map all the possible sequences.

What I would like is a way to "render" the output in a string as I would see it in the terminal. Is there a Python package that given a string with terminal sequences like `s = r'\x1b[12;5H\nSomething'` would just give me the string     `Something`? again, this string is just an example of one of the possible responses I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps something like a [ansi parsing library](https://github.com/helgefmi/ansiterm) would do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's too much for it, I'm getting an `Exception: Invalid escape sequence, input[:20]='\x1b(B\x1b)0\x1b[?1h\x1b=\x1b[H\x1b[J\n'` error.